# Path of the flags XFCE (layout keyboard)

Tags: xfce, layout

Under XFCE. Which path are the flags associated to keyboard layouts located in?

Those I find in

```
 /usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/
```

do not correspond to the flags shown.

Or where is the file that associates flags to languages (not every language corresponds to a country). I'd like to associate a flag to the Latin American Spanish layout --- xfce loads a plain text icon containing `lat` instead of a flag.

The solution that didn't work was to replace the `es.svg` by `wished-flag.svg`. I load then Spanish as layout but the keyboard is quite different. So I really would like to modify the file.

Comment: That is where the images are installed for the xkb utility in xfce http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin You will need to be more specific in your question if you are referring to another keyboard layout application.

Answer (score 3):

The .svg files for the country flags in xfce4 are located in the `/usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a flag in `.svg` format. Go to (as Kevin Bowen mentions)

> /usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/

and copy the file `wished-flag.svg` in that directory (or rename), with the name

> shorthand-of-the-layout.svg

For instance, the `latam` flag does not exist. By creating `latam.svg` and copying the icon there one gets rid of the no-flag problem.